# ansible undefined variable for lineinfile

Tags: ansible-2.x

I have a playbook as below , while i'm trying to have a stdout locally on my control server i'm getting into an error:

can someone hist me what mistake i'm doing

Below is the playbook ..

```
 ---
    - name: Playbook to add a host into PAM portal....
      hosts: all
      remote_user: root
      gather_facts: False
      serial: 1
      tasks:
        - name: replace line
          lineinfile:
            dest: /etc/auto.master
            state: present
            regexp: '^(.*)auto_master_lnx_bangalore1(.*)$'
            line: '+auto_master_lnx_bnglrdpc'
            backrefs: yes
            backup: yes
          register: auto_m

        - name: Storing STDOUT locally
          lineinfile: create=yes dest=/data/fab/CyberArk_Play/aut_master.logs line="{{ auto_m.stdout }}"
          delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

The Error code which i'm getting is as below:

```
fatal: [fox-dev001]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 's                  tdout'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/data/fab/CyberArk_Play/replace_auto_master.yml': line 18, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file                   depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Storing STDOUT locally\n      ^ here\n\nexception typ                  e: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}
```

Comment: Why do you think `auto_m` should have `stdout` attribute?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov, that's what i'm missing to understand and seeking hints why it should not be, as being a newbie learner..

Comment: Use `debug` module to see what's inside `auto_m`.

Comment: It gives same error with debug even.

Comment: use `debug: var=auto_m`.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov it works, can you explain  abit pls.